# Strongly typed discriminated deserializer

Tags: typescript

I'm hoping to get some advice on if / how I can leverage TypeScript to strongly type a function that works something like this:

```
function createDeserializer(typeDeserializers) {
    return (data) => {
        const deserializer = typeDeserializers[data.__type];
        return deserializer(data);
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping for is being able to do something like this:

```
const personDeserializer = createDeserializer({
    'employee': (data) => new Employee(data),
    'customer': (data) => new Customer(data)
});

const person1 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'employee', ... });
const person2 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'customer', ... });

// Here TypeScript knows that person1 is an 'Employee' instance, and person2 is a 'Customer' instance.
```

I figure I need to do some kind of key mapping on the `typeDeserializers` property and map this to the return value somehow, but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
class Employee {
    constructor(data: any) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    position: string;
}
class Customer {
    constructor(data: any) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    clv: number;
}

type DeserializerTypes = { [n in string]: (data: {}) => {} };

function createDeserializer<DS extends DeserializerTypes>(typeDeserializers: DS) {
    return <T extends keyof DS>(data: { __type: T }): ReturnType<DS[T]> => {
        const deserializer = typeDeserializers[data.__type];
        return deserializer(data) as ReturnType<DS[T]>;
    }
}

const personDeserializer = createDeserializer({
    'employee': (data) => new Employee(data),
    'customer': (data) => new Customer(data)
});

const person1 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'employee' }); // inferred as Employee
const person2 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'customer' }); // inferred as Customer

console.log(person1.position);
console.log(1000 + person2.clv);
```

But it gets a bit trickier if you allow properties in deserializer argument, but still want TypeScript to infer exact type:

```
function createDeserializer<DS extends DeserializerTypes>(typeDeserializers: DS) {
    return <T extends keyof DS, D extends { __type: T }>(data: D): ReturnType<DS[D['__type']]> => {
        const deserializer = typeDeserializers[data.__type];
        return deserializer(data) as ReturnType<DS[T]>;
    }
}

const personDeserializer = createDeserializer({
    'employee': (data) => new Employee(data),
    'customer': (data) => new Customer(data)
});

const person1 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'employee', position: 'a' });
const person2 = personDeserializer({ __type: 'customer', clv: 12 }); 

console.log(person1.position);
console.log(1000 + person2.clv);
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much!